# Searching a key which is period separated using Boon api

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I'm using Boon api for parsing a json string. In my json string one of the key is separated with a period example-(com.stack.demo). Now, the problem is that boon considers this period and separates the key. In short I'm trying to lookup a string in xpath fashion. In xpath you have a delimeter '[]' in which we can place the period separated string and xpath (json path) searches the string correctly.
I want to achieve the same through boon, any ideas...refer to the code below -

```
Map<String, Object> rickJsonList1 = (Map<String, Object>) Boon.fromJson(input);
System.out.println(Boon.atIndex(rickJsonList1, "eventHeader.com.schema.Header"));
```

The json is as below -

```
{"eventHeader" : {"com.schema.Header": "test"}}
```

I need to get the value "test"...

Comment: checked the Boon api, this doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried bracket-notation?

```
?['eventHeader']['com.schema.Header']
```